# Transition effect on both thumbnail and H1 link when hover thumbnail

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I've been struggling for a couple of days with this issue. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is the same as this : http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/

Highlight the link when the mouse is on the thumbnail which also has an transition effect. I know It probably has something to do with adjacent siblings selector, but i'm sort of new to this and I can't manage to find the right answer on stackoverflow. Here's my code so far :

HTML

```
<div class="postBoxInner"><div class="pic">
                <?php
                if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        //the_post_thumbnail();?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_image_url(); ?>&amp;h=170&amp;w=347&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                    <?php } else {
                        echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/nothumb.jpg"  alt="No Thumbnail"/>';
                    }?></a></div>

                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

And the CSS

```
#content .postBoxInner .pic{
border:2px solid #d8d8d8;
height:170px;
width:347px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#content .postBoxInner img {
height:171px;
width:348px;
margin:auto;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: all 1s ease;
}

#content .postBoxInner img:hover{
 -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
}

#content .postBox .postBoxInner h2 {
line-height:20pt;
font-size:18px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:normal;
padding:12px 0 10px;
}

#content .postBoxInner h2 a {
color:#000000;
}

#content .postBoxInner h2 a:hover {
color:#c71515;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

PS: English is not my first language so please bear with me :)

EDIT :

Well I just figured it out. It was in fact an adjacent sibling selector issue and It was actually really easy =)

```
#content .postBoxInner .pic {
border:2px solid #d8d8d8;
height:170px;
width:347px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#content .postBoxInner .pic:hover+h2 a {
color:#c71515;
text-decoration:none;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/4xymL/6/)

Try this

### css

```
    .pic {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:fixed;
   }
    .animationZoomOut {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    }
    .animationZoomIN {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    }
```

### code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".pic").hover(function () {

         $('img').removeClass('animationZoomOut').addClass('animationZoomIN');
     },

     function () {
         $('img').removeClass('animationZoomIN').addClass('animationZoomOut');
     });
 });
```

### html

```
<div class="pic">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: I appreciate your effort =). I think I should have kept my question more simple though, Sorry. What I want to do is make the H2 link change his color when I rollover the image.

Comment: @Ben your question was not what you need to have.Just look at your question heading and content, does it seems like a question to change the color

Answer (score 0):

I would say use Jquery for that effect, I used it recently in a project for a restaurant and i found it was easier to use jQuery. In the example the transition is not smooth but easy to make it smooth.

Check out this link for a examples and the example code.

[Code and example](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1168/jQuery-multiple-Image-Hover-effect)

Im not sure about this but maby try use:`transform 0.5s linear 0s;`

Comment: Thank you very much for you fast answer. But I think I may have been unclear. My problem is not the transition itself. I just want both the transition (thumbnail and H1 tag) to happen at the same time when you put the cursor on the thumbnail only.